# The modulus operator (%) in python

Tags: python-3.x

I am new to programming, and I chose to learn Python, and I came across this operator (%) called modulus, but I don't understand it, can some explain it to me in more detail!

Comment: `a % b` returns the remainder of the division of `a` by `b`. e.g `16 % 10` would return 6

Answer (score 3):

It is used to calculate the remainder of an integer division, like `5 % 3` which yields 2. It returns the remainder for all numeric operands on the left-hand-side (that is, if the first operands is an integer, fraction, float, Decimal numbers.

But it is also used after strings to interpolate data into the string, using a legacy markup from C's printf - like in :

```
"Hello %s. Your age is %d" % ("Daniel", "23")
```

Which yields:

```
'Hello Daniel. Your age is 23'
```

In this use, `%` is used as an operator after the string. The `%` ocurrences inside the string are the markup to indicate placeholders for an objetct to be rendered as a string, and an object to be rendered as an integer number. The parameters to be rendered are on the tuple, on the right-hand-side of the operator.

This mode works for strings (`str`) or `bytes` objects. 
And last, but not least, in Python all operators are overloadable, depending on the class of the objects being used as operands - so you might as well find `%` doing other things - all that is needed is that the class of the objects being operated implement the `__mod__` or `__rmod__` methods.

Answer (score 1):

Modulus Operator (%) returns the remainder of the division.

For Example:

- 5 % 3 = 2
- 4 % 2 = 0
- 3 % 5 = 3
- 10.5 % 3 = 1.5

Answer (score 0):

Modulus (%) operator returns the reminder after division operator.

Example:

```
5 % 3 = 2
10 % 9 = 1
10 % 9.0 = 1.0
```